# What is the work done in making a cone?

Tags: calculus

**Problem:** A child is building a sand structure at the beach. Find the work done if the weight density of the sand is $\delta=140$ lb/ft$^3$ and the structure is a cone of height $1$ ft and diameter $2$ ft.

**My Attempt:** To be frank, I have tried to think about this problem, but I am quite clueless as to how should I even start solving this problem. The real issue that I am facing is that I don't understand how can I compute the work done in making something because $W=\int Fdx$ and in this problem I can't deduce an expression for $F$ in terms of $x$. So any initial ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: The work you should calculate is lifting the sand from the ground. So the relevant force is gravitation $F=gm$ where $g=9.81 m/s^2$ is gravity and $m$ is mass. For the full solution you need to figure out how much sand in the cone is at what height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice the cone into parallel horizontal layers, each at height $y$ off the ground and having thickness $\Delta y$.  Then the incremental work $\Delta W$ required to build this layer (that is, raise that much sand to that height) is
$$
    \Delta W \approx \Delta F \,y
$$
where $\Delta F$ is the weight of the layer.  That's from the force $\times$ distance rule of work.  Now the weight is proportional to the volume:
$$
    \Delta W \approx \Delta V\cdot \delta\,y
$$
[Trouble spot for those more familiar with the metric system:  The density of sand given in the problem is a *weight* density in pounds (force) per unit of volume.  So $\delta$ times volume is force, not mass, and further scaling by $g$ is not needed.]
The layer is basically a disk with thickness $\Delta y$; let its radius be called $r$.  Then:
$$
    \Delta W \approx \pi r^2 \,\Delta y\cdot \delta \,y
$$
Now consider that the radius of the bottommost layer ($y=0$) is $1$ foot and the height is $1$ foot.  So the radius of the layer at height $y$ is $1-y$.  Therefore
$$
    \Delta W \approx \pi (1-y)^2\,\Delta y \cdot \delta \,y 
    = \delta\pi(1-y)^2y\,\Delta y
$$
Do a little unit analysis here: $\delta$ has units of $\text{lb}/\text{ft}^3$.  In the expression for $\Delta W$ we multiply $\delta$ by four lengths, all measured in feet: $(1-y)$ twice, $y$, and $\Delta y$.  So the units of $\Delta W$ are foot-pounds, as work should be.

Summing up all the layers, and letting their thickness tend to zero, we get an integral
$$
    W = \int_0^1 \delta\pi(1-y)^2y\,dy = \frac{\pi \delta}{12}\text{ft}\cdot\text{lb}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry of the problem suggests to use cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta, z)$. The work done to lift (quasistatically) from the ground $z_i=0$ to its final position $z_f=z$ on a mass $\delta\,r\,\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dr\mathrm dz$ of sand is $\delta gz\,r\,\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dr\mathrm dz$ because that work is done to change its heigh and hence, its gravitational potential energy. The radius of the base is $1$, so, the max value of $r$ changes with the heigh as $1-z$. Summing over all that sand,

$$W=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-z}\int_0^{2\pi}\delta gz\,r\,\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dr\mathrm dz=$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^1\int_0^{1-z}\delta gz\,r\,\mathrm dr\mathrm dz=$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^1\delta gz\,\left[\frac{r^2}{2}\right]_0^{1-z}\mathrm dz=$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^1\delta g\frac{z(1-z)^2}{2}\mathrm dz=$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^1\delta g\left[x^4/8-2x^3/6+x^2/4\right]_0^1\mathrm dz=$$

$$=\frac{\delta g\pi}{12}=\frac{1}{12}140\pi\,32.174\,lb·ft^2/s^2$$